# How to custom listview that can expand and collapse and shows fixed number item （not zero）？

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

I have think about ExpandableListView， but it show no item when collapsed. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Post some code, log.

Comment: https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView    I was wondering the AnimatedExpandableListView   can be customed to show 3 or some fixed number item when collapsed